# Fetching a single record is outputting more than the records contents and json.parse not logging the correct data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I set up a new table called triggers. What I am doing is setting up a simple binary system that triggers things from showing or not showing. The code below is from an attempt I just made at doing this.

I'm running into two issues with the code below.

1. The `echo json_encode` is actually echoing onto the file's page. I have never had this happen before, so I'm unsure why it is doing so.

The echoed result is this:

```
{"specialPopStatus":{"setting":"1","0":"1"}}
```

The only number that should be showing up is `1`. I don't understand where the trailing 0 and 1 are coming from.

[image]

2. The console.log results from the JSON.parse is [object Object]. I don't understand why, if at the very least, the 1, 0 and 1 isn't outputting.

Ultimately, all I am wanting is the `setting` result from the db for the single record I indicate by the name. Then I want to fetch this record via my ajax function. It will always be either 0 or 1.

What am I doing wrong?

PHP

```
try {
    $con = getConfig('pdo');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $special_pop_sql = "
        SELECT setting
        FROM triggers
        WHERE trigger_name = 'Special Pop'
        LIMIT 1
    ";

    if ($special_pop_stmt = $con->prepare($special_pop_sql)) {
        $special_pop_stmt->execute();
        $special_pop_row = $special_pop_stmt->fetch();
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode(['specialPopStatus' => $special_pop_row]);
```

JS

```
var status2 = 0;
function ajaxSpecialPopTrigger() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/php/triggers.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);

            specialPopStatus = obj.specialPopStatus;
            status2 = specialPopStatus;
            console.log(status2 + ' This is the status');
        }
    });
}
ajaxSpecialPopTrigger();
```

EDIT - New JS:

```
var status2 = 0;
function ajaxSpecialPopTrigger() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/php/triggers.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //obj = JSON.parse(data);

            //Catalog Requests
            specialPopStatus = data.specialPopStatus;
            status2 = specialPopStatus;
            console.log(status2 + ' This is the status');
        }
    });
}
ajaxSpecialPopTrigger();
```

Comment: I think you mean you have setup a TABLE called triggers. There is a non subtile difference

Comment: Why are you preparing a query that has NO Parameters?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep, you are correct. Edited.

Comment: @RiggsFollyThat is the only way I know how to do a PDO statement.

Comment: You could have done a [simple `->query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the extra data in the json string is that you use

```
$special_pop_row = $special_pop_stmt->fetch();
```

the default of which is to return an assoc array **AND** a numeric array, notice the data value is `1` in both cases.

So fix that by doing this small mod

```
$special_pop_row = $special_pop_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Also in the javascript because you have given

```
datatype: 'json',
```

as the paramter, you dont have to parse the json as jQuery will do that for you

So the javascript code be written

```
var status2 = 0;
function ajaxSpecialPopTrigger() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/php/triggers.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //obj = JSON.parse(data);

            specialPopStatus = data.specialPopStatus;
            //status2 = specialPopStatus;
            console.log(specialPopStatus + ' This is the status');
        }
    });
}
ajaxSpecialPopTrigger();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. The echoed `json_encode` is now correct. BTW - if I take away the echo part of it, will the JS file still read it? However, the console.log statement is now reading `undefined`.

Comment: No, the `echo json_encode(['specialPopStatus' => $special_pop_row]);` is what passes data back to the waiting ajax function

Comment: Then how do I get it so the results aren't showing up on the page? I've never had the json_encode actually show up on the page. I also edited my question to show the updated JS regarding why it is now showing up as undefined.

Comment: I figured out why the `json_encode` results were outputting to my page. I forgot to delete my `include_once` code for the php file. I still can't figure out why the results are showing undefined in the `console.log` though.